# How to remove sub seconds part of Date object

Tags: java

java.util.Date gets stored as 2010-09-03 15:33:22.246 when the SQL data type is timestamp, how do I set the sub seconds to zero (e.g. 246 in this case) prior to storing the record.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("S");
       Date d = new Date();
       System.out.println(df.format(d));
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
       d.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
       System.out.println(df.format(d));

}
```

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way would be something like:

```
long time = date.getTime();
date.setTime((time / 1000) * 1000);
```

In other words, clear out the last three digits of the "millis since 1970 UTC".

I believe that will *also* clear the nanoseconds part if it's a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: that time will be a long time ago!  More like date.setTime(date.getTime() - date.getTime() % 1000);

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I remove hours, minutes, and seconds from a millisecond value, leaving just the date? I have been doing the math but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Churro: Without a time zone, there *is* no date. You can construct a `Calendar` with the appropriate time zone, set the time in it, and then fetch the date from that. Or personally, I'd use Joda Time.

Comment: Cool mathematic solution!

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.Calendar` can help you.

```
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.setTime(date);
    instance.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    date = instance.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way by java 8 Instant api

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Instant instant = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

or

```
Date now = new Date();
Instant instant = now.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Apache Commons DateUtils, for example:

```
DateUtils.setMilliseconds(new Date(), 0);
```