# How to remove milliseconds from Date Object format in Java

Tags: java, java.util.date

Since the `java.util.Date` object stores Date as `2014-01-24 17:33:47.214`, but I want the Date format as `2014-01-24 17:33:47`. **I want to remove the milliseconds part.**

I checked a question related to my question...

[How to remove sub seconds part of Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3634771/2764279)

I've tried the given answer

```
long time = date.getTime();
date.setTime((time / 1000) * 1000);
```

but I've got my result Date format as `2014-01-24 17:33:47.0`. How can I remove that `0` from my Date format???

Comment: The date is irrelevant. Show us the **formatting** code.

Comment: A date object represents long milliseconds, you cant divide it by 1000 and just show the hour.. may be you need to go through the documentation

Comment: I believe they meant to use `date.setTime(Math.round(time / 1000) * 1000);` (see answer below)

Comment: @NickG: Given that `time / 1000` will always be an integer, what's the point in rounding it?

Comment: The time value is a long so there is no point rounding it.

Comment: @Jason, too right. It is a long. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basic answer is, you can't.  The value returned by `Date#toString` is a representation of the `Date` object and it carries no concept of format other then what it uses internally for the `toString` method.

Generally this shouldn't be used for display purpose (except for rare occasions)

Instead you should be using some kind of [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

For example...

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date));
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(date));
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(date));
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG).format(date));
```

Will output something like...

```
Thu Jan 30 16:29:31 EST 2014
30/01/2014 4:29:31 PM
30/01/14 4:29 PM
30/01/2014 4:29:31 PM
30 January 2014 4:29:31 PM
```

If you get really stuck, you can customise it further by using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but I would avoid this if you can, as not everybody uses the same date/time formatting ;)

Comment: It was Jaburary, 2014 when I answered this question, Java 8 didn't come out until March, 2014, therefore we didn't have the "new and shinny" `java.time` APIs.  So, on that fact, what is wrong with the answer that it would attract a downvote? I agree, Basil's answer is more up-to-date and was made 3 years after this one

Answer (score 36):

## tl;dr

Lop off the fractional second.

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()                         // Convert from legacy class to modern class. Returns a `Instant` object.
              .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )   // Generate new `Instant` object based on the values of the original, but chopping off the fraction-of-second.
```

Hide the fractional second, when generating a `String`.

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()                         // Convert from legacy class to modern class. Returns a `Instant` object.
              .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )          // Return a `OffsetDateTime` object. 
              .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ). // Ask the `OffsetDateTime` object to generate a `String` with text representing its value, in a format defined in the `DateTimeFormatter` object.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `Instant`

Convert your old `java.util.Date` object to a `java.time.Instant` by calling new method added to the old class.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

[image: Table of types of date-time classes in modern java.time versus legacy.]

## Truncate

If you want to change value of the data itself to drop the fraction of a second, you can truncate. The java.time classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so we generate a new object rather than alter (mutate) the original.

```
Instant instantTruncated = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

## Generating string

If instead of truncating you merely want to suppress the display of the fractional seconds when generating a string representing the date-time value, define a formatter to suit your needs.

For example, "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" makes no mention of a fractional second, so any milliseconds contained in the data simply does not appear in the generated string.

Convert `Instant` to a `OffsetDateTime` for more flexible formatting.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
String output = odt.format( f );
```

## Time zone

Note that your Question ignores the issue of time zone. If you intended to use UTC, the above code works as both `Date` and `Instant` are in UTC by definition. If instead you want to perceive the given data through the lens of some region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone. Search Stack Overflow for `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime` class names for much more info.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Upvoted. Even shorter: `Date now = Date.from(Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS));`, and, in general, stop using Date since it's deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Truncate to Seconds (no milliseconds), return a new Date:

```
public Date truncToSec(Date date) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Date newDate = c.getTime();
    return newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `SimpleDateFormatter`. Please see the following code.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date now = date.getTime();
System.out.println(formatter.format(now));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Apache's DateUtils:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
...
DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.SECOND)
```

Comment: I learned painfully, that this doesn't truncate MILLISECOND. If you want to truncate milliseconds, use Calendar.SECOND.

Comment: @Dargenn my bad, I was translating from code of mine. I've modified my answer.

Comment: There also is a `round` method that rounds instead of truncates. For those who want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to format the date as necessary.  Due to the diversity of possible combinations, I will simply include the documentation link here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Your code will look something similar to the following:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the accepted answer given at the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634833/3635692) works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("S");
       Date d = new Date();
       System.out.println(df.format(d));
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
       d.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
       System.out.println(df.format(d));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following date formatter:

```
import java.text.*;
SimpleDateFormat tmp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
System.out.println(tmp.format(date));
```

Comment: What do you expect the benefit of calling `Math.round` with a `long` value to be? It's already an integer....

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks Jon, I've updated the answer with your feedback!

Comment: You've now got the same code that the OP has in the question, which doesn't do what he wants it to. The problem is really about formatting - and if the OP uses a format which doesn't include the milliseconds part, there's no need to change the value in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Please see the section below it, regarding formatting.

Comment: `HH:mm:ss SSS` will still print the milliseconds, the OP is trying to get rid of them altogether...